# How can I synchronize my all accounts?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, network-profile

For example, I updated my Stack Overflow profile, and I want to apply that profile to all my network profiles. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the bottom of the page at, for example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164923/monstermmorpg?tab=accounts, you will notice the following three buttons:

[image: screenshot]

The first one is the one you are looking for. All of those buttons are listed in your user account, in all the SE sites where you have an account. Just go to the SE with the account containing the data you want copied in the other accounts, and you will be all set up.

Comment: What changes between different sites is the name of the SE site shown in the first and the third button; their purpose is the same for all the SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably be covered somewhere already, but...

- go to your [profile view and select  the 'accounts' tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310370/monstermmorpg?tab=accounts),
- scroll to the very bottom of the page,
- select the first option 'Copy Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts'.

Comment: thanks . i will accept when it is available.